# IntelliJ Maven/Git Auto-prepend license file/header

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, licensing

I'm not quite sure where to ask this, but is there a way for maven compile / git push/commit to auto import a license file or section?

Let's say I have the file 'LICENSE' in the root of my project, which uploads to my git project and is available for all to see. Is there a way for each file to prepend the LICENSE file above the class when you commit a git (intellij) or maybe somehow using maven?

Answer (score 1):

If all people committing to your project are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can use its [Copyright feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/copyright.html?search=copyright) (it's a "Plugin", but a standard one built into the IDE) to require a particular notice within each file.

If you need it to actually be added via Git regardless of the IDE used, then you should look into [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which allows for deployment of any custom logic you need to happen upon each commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven build order. "package" is after "test".
You could have a test that walks the src code and prepends the license where there is none.

A 'maven deploy' would give you all files correct.
But

- it changes src after the compile phase. So the test runs, strictly speaking, not on the exact src code. You basically have to run until you get some feedback that no src files where changed.
- this is independent from git. So you must be careful to do extra git commit/pushes.